# 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Internal Server Error

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

Why is it telling me this?

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /ci_series/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Problem:

Page does not want to display this simple function:

```
<?php
class Mycal extends CI_Controller {

    function display() {

        $this->load->library('calendar');

        echo $this->calendar->generate();
    }
}
```

I am using the framework codeIgniter

Error log:

```
[Mon Aug 01 17:10:45 2011] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/ci_series/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Mon Aug 01 17:10:52 2011] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/ci_series/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Comment: Have you done what the error message suggested, e.g. have you looked at the server error log? What did it say? If not, do so now and add the error message to your question.

Comment: What you URI looks like?

Comment: http://localhost/ci_series/mycal/display

Comment: Are you sure your httpd.conf is loading mod_rewrite? You need to make sure `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` is not commented out.

Comment: I put the updated code in now, nothing is commented out.

Comment: Dale, please explain how you fixed it and mark the correct answer below as "accepted".  Otherwise post your solution as an answer and "accept" your own answer.  StackOverflow is also for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check whether you have Rewrite module enabled?(most of the this will be the reason)

for Wamp go to httpd.conf and uncomment

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

If you try to use module which is not loaded you will get 500 internal server error.

> Check your modules used in .htaccess file and check httpd.conf whether used modules are loaded

Comment: This solution worked for me with the following .htaccess  
---->
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

Answer (score 3):

**500 Internal Server Errors** can commonly be caused by the improper uploading of a critical file.

Your `.htaccess` file should have been uploaded in "**ASCII/text mode**" and not "**binary mode**".

Comment: @Dale:  If my answer solved it, please "accept" it by clicking the green check-mark.   If not, please accept the correct answer or post the solution as an answer and accept your own answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to start Apache httpd.exe (I am using x64 VC11 example here)

```
http://www.apachelounge.com/download/VC11/
```

Be sure that you have installed Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 : VC11 vcredist_x64/86.exe

```
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679
```

You may need to have Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 (VS2012.3)

```
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679 (vcredirect.exe)
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2835600
```

Unzip httpd-2.4.4-win64-VC11.zip and copy paste in

```
C:\Apache24
```

Unzip modules-2.4-win64-VC11.zip and copy paste them in

```
C:\Apache24\modules

http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=25091
```

For further info on the modules see the Apache Lounge VC10 Win64 download page and/or the readme in the .zip's there.

```
http://www.apachelounge.com/download/win64/
```

In

```
C:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf
```

un-comment (remove # sign) starting below this like copy pasted list in here

```
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so

LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_socache_module modules/mod_authn_socache.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_dbd_module modules/mod_authz_dbd.so
LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule buffer_module modules/mod_buffer.so
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
LoadModule data_module modules/mod_data.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule heartbeat_module modules/mod_heartbeat.so
LoadModule heartmonitor_module modules/mod_heartmonitor.so
LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module modules/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule log_debug_module modules/mod_log_debug.so
LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
LoadModule lua_module modules/mod_lua.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_express_module modules/mod_proxy_express.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
LoadModule ratelimit_module modules/mod_ratelimit.so
LoadModule reflector_module modules/mod_reflector.so
LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
LoadModule request_module modules/mod_request.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so
LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so
LoadModule session_cookie_module modules/mod_session_cookie.so
LoadModule session_crypto_module modules/mod_session_crypto.so
LoadModule session_dbd_module modules/mod_session_dbd.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule slotmem_plain_module modules/mod_slotmem_plain.so
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
LoadModule socache_dbm_module modules/mod_socache_dbm.so
LoadModule socache_memcache_module modules/mod_socache_memcache.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule watchdog_module modules/mod_watchdog.so
LoadModule xml2enc_module modules/mod_xml2enc.so
```

Then find

```
C:\Apache24\bin\ApacheMonitor.exe
```

and double click on it.

Then in Command Prompt (CMD.exe) type

```
C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe
```

and press enter. It shows any error remaining.

Build with the latest Update 3 Visual Studio® 2012 aka VC11. VC11 has improvements, fixes and optimizations over VC10 in areas like Performance, MemoryManagement and Stability. For example code quality tuning and improvements done across different code generation areas for "speed". And makes more use of modern processors and win7, win8, 2008 and Server 2012 internal features.

The VC11 binaries loads VC11, VC10 and VC9 modules, and does not run on XP and 2003. Minimum system required: Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8 / 8.1, Windows Vista SP2, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2012 / R2

After you have downloaded and before you attempt to install it, you should make sure that it is intact and has not been tampered with. Use the PGP Signature and/or the SHA Checksums to verify the integrity.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be extending `CI_Controller` instead of `Controller`? Otherwise it's not inheriting core CI methods.  If this doesn't deal with the 500 error, check your error_log and post what it says.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in .htaccess file as it is in my blog http://thephpcode.com/blog/codeigniter/removed-index_php_url

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ci_series/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

6 (PHP Bug fix)  Server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete request!

Project - Make Knowledge Free

Video Link - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uqhzWlqN3uc

Here , i was unable to load the site resources because i was getting this server error . When i read tackoverfow , i saw this was a common issue . i Was wondering how i have dissapointed apache so much ...later when i saw the error logs i saw that i had made use of a rewrite rule but unfortunately my apache on my wamp server didn't have this module turned on !

So , it was giving the bad server error !
So to get around it ,i could do 2 things ...i.e either turn on the apache rewrite engine module on using the wamp manager or comment out the rewrite rule if it was not that important !

On doing the former ,  everything works and i have recorded the whole thing !

I am sure that it will help people !

Cheers ,

Amlan Dutta

Error message - Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: Hi. Maybe you could write just the solution? It will help people understand it and use it better, Right now, it's not clear what exactly you did that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue until I changed the permissions on the PHP file from 664 to 644, then the error went away.