# Cannot target files in Code Igniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

Hello I have created a new subdomain of my domain and I am building a code igniter application. Everything is working OK except the fact that I cannot target the stylesheet or any other file in the application.

I have structure like this:

```
Root
/application
/css
/images
/js
/system
/userguide
```

Inside the css folder I have a style.css file.

I have tried to add this stylesheet to my application and it is not possible.
The strange thing is that even when I the url directly in the browser it sais that it cannot find the file.

I am on Bluehost, not sure if that has something to do with the configuration of the server or the configuration of the codeigniter.

Please help as I have tryied every possible method.

Thanks to all in advance!

Comment: What is the url that you are hitting to get the CSS file ?

Comment: This is the url: http://arg.digitalcube.gr/css/style.css

Comment: Have u set the base_url in config file ?

Comment: I have this in the application/config/config.php

$config['base_url'] = 'http://arg.digitalcube.gr/';

Comment: Just one semicolon should be there..Also i believe u have changed your htaccess file to remove index.php from url. Maybe check there once again

Comment: In the htaccess the only thing that I have is:

# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

How should that be structure? I am such a noob!

Answer (score 0):

At first it should be better to put images, css and js folders in a folder named "public" on the root.

Then you can use this code:

`<LINK href= "<?=site_url(); ?>public/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Another way you can include a css file is by using the [template library](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/).

If the problem insists then you may change your root .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your htaccess file to

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|js|robots\.txt|favicon \.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is standard which i have been using in my many CI Apps and it works fine :)

Also this htaccess file should be alongwith application, system folder(outside application folder)

Comment: I did not wanted to have the index.php in my urls that's why I have deleted this entry:

$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';

and made it

$config['index_page'] = '';

Can you please help to remove the index.php properly and reach my stylesheet? I am having 500 Internal Server Error now

Comment: yes. you do have to remove index_page from config.. are u sure you have exactly copied the htacess code from above and pasted in htaccess file inside the main app folder ?

Comment: yes in the .htaccess file in the root of the arg.digitalcube.gr has only the lines you sent me. Nothing else. Should there be any wrapping around them? Something like <if mod_rewrite>...</if>

Comment: I am able to see the CSS file which u posted above. It is accessible

Comment: I cannot get to the file. I am getting the following: http://awesomescreenshot.com/03212px02a

Comment: i am sorry then.. Maybe u can try these links which has same problem as yours [link](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/105774/) & other is [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900162/500-internal-server-error)

Comment: I have also tried other browser / chrome / mozilla / ie all seems to display the same problem

Comment: let me know when u find the solution :) also do check the link2 i mentioned.. it seems more closer to your problem :)

Comment: I have managed to figure that out and I have posted my solution above. Thank you so much Jigar for pointing me there!

Answer (score 0):

Insert following line in your html file:

```
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Double check that you have copied the file with correct name in css folder.

I assume that your other settings are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve my own problems after reading the links that Jigar pointed me to.

My solution is to add in the htaccess file of the root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```