# .htaccess causing 500 error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have only a single line in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Taking that line out makes the error go away. I've checked as many places as I know of for the AllowOverride rule (but I know next to nothing about how that works) and I thiiiiink it's set correctly, but I don't know for sure.

I can't figure out what's going on and I'm not sure what to even check. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure mod_rewrite is enabled on your server (on debian based systems it a2enmod rewrite) reload apache and go

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900162/500-internal-server-error) "Your .htaccess file should have been uploaded in "ASCII/text mode" and not "binary mode"."

Comment: @Orangepill How would I check if mod_rewrite is enabled?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Enable the rewrite module in apache by command on ( for Ubuntu )

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing it with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine On
</IfModule
```

Comment: That's because you haven't loaded mod_rewrite in apache

Comment: If it is ubuntu server, then try command `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: Aha! @kuldeep.kamboj Please post this comment as an answer!